# Is there a way to add x amount of new components based on clicks?

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-design-system

I am wanting to add new components to specific section of the screen depending on when a [menu item](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-button-menu/example) is clicked. The menu items would be mobile phone and landline phone. Anytime one of the menu items were selected, I would want to add a few input fields to have rendered in their specific section on screen.

For example lets say I have 1 mobile number and 1 landline number on screen already, I would like to add 1 new mobile number by selecting the menu item from the menu to "add new mobile number". I then would want to see the new input fields to render above or under the phone number on screen already. I know we could render on click but am more curious if there is a way that can dynamically do it depending on number of clicks and the different options at hand.

code provided to help illustrate question/issue:

```
<template>
        <lightning-card  title="Phone Number(s)">
                <lightning-button-menu alternative-text="Show menu" variant="border-filled" icon-name="utility:add" class="slds-m-left_large" slot="actions">
                    <lightning-menu-item value="mobilePhone" label="Add New Mobile Phone"></lightning-menu-item>
                    <lightning-menu-item value="landlinePhone" label="Add New Landline Phone"></lightning-menu-item>
                </lightning-button-menu>
                <lightning-input type="tel" label="Phone number here before menu click" name="phone3" value="343-343-3434" pattern="[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}"></lightning-input>
                <lightning-input type="tel" label="New phone number added here after menu item click" name="phone2" placeholder="areacode-phone"></lightning-input>      
         </lightning-card>
</template>
```

Comment: I'm not clear on what you mean by "depending on number of clicks"? In your example, you can only click on the menu item once.

Comment: ah sorry, I am meaning like lets say someone clicks the first menu item 5 times. I do not know of a proper way of rendering that component 5 times that are all unique. That is what I am meaning by "depending on number of clicks". Usually in other frameworks you could use a conditional that will render a component x amount of times depending on clicks, but I am unsure of how that works/how to do that on salesforce

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by using arrays to hold the list of values, then add to that array for each time the menu option is used. I wrote a quick [demo](https://webcomponents.dev/edit/yRwU2xPudnG3EK165S58/src/app.html) for this.

```
<template>
    <lightning-card title="Phone Number(s)">
        <lightning-button-menu onselect={handleMenuAction} alternative-text="Show menu" variant="border-filled"
            icon-name="utility:add" class="slds-m-left_large" slot="actions">
            <lightning-menu-item value="mobilePhone" label="Add New Mobile Phone"></lightning-menu-item>
            <lightning-menu-item value="landlinePhone" label="Add New Landline Phone"></lightning-menu-item>
        </lightning-button-menu>
        <lightning-card title="Mobile Phone(s)">
            <lightning-input for:each={mobilePhones} for:item="phone" key={phone.index} type="tel" label="Phone"
                value={phone.number} pattern="[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}"></lightning-input>
        </lightning-card>
        <lightning-card title="Landline Phone(s)">
            <lightning-input for:each={landlinePhones} for:item="phone" key={phone.index} type="tel" label="Phone"
                value={phone.number} pattern="[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}"></lightning-input>
        </lightning-card>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

---

```
import { LightningElement } from "lwc";

export default class App extends LightningElement {
  mobilePhones = [{index:0,number:''}];
  landlinePhones = [{index:0,number:''}];;
  handleMenuAction(event) {
    switch (event.detail.value) {
      case 'mobilePhone': 
        this.mobilePhones = [...this.mobilePhones, {index:this.mobilePhones.length+1,number:''}];
        break;
      case 'landlinePhone': 
        this.landlinePhones = [...this.landlinePhones, {index:this.landlinePhones.length+1,number:''}];
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

Note that this answer doesn't address some other core features, such as updating the values in memory correctly. These will be added to the demo shortly.

Comment: this is exactly the type of insight I needed on addressing this issue. Thank you!